# Haskell: do notation and return in Monads

Tags: haskell, monads

Suppose I have following code

```
do {x <- (Just 3); y <- (Just 5); return (x:y:[])}
```

Which outputs `Just [3,5]`

How does haskell know that output value should be in `Maybe` monad? I mean `return` could output `[[3, 5]]`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
do {x <- (Just 3); y <- (Just 5); return (x:y:[])}
```

desugars to

```
Just 3 >>= \x -> Just 5 >>= \y -> return $ x:y:[]
```

Since the type of `>>=` is `Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` and per argument `Just 3` (alternatively `Just 5`) we have `m ~ Maybe`, the return type of the expression must be some `Maybe` type.

---

There is a possibility to make this return `[[3, 5]]` using something called [natural transformations](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+transformation) from [category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory). Because there exists a natural transformation from `Maybe a` to `[a]`, namely

```
alpha :: Maybe a -> [a]
alpha Nothing  = []
alpha (Just a) = [a]
```

we have that your desired function is simply the natural transformation applied to the result:

```
alpha (Just 3 >>= \x -> Just 5 >>= \y -> return $ x:y:[])
-- returns [[3, 5]]
```

Since this is a natural transformation, you can also apply `alpha` first and your function second:

```
alpha (Just 3) >>= \x -> alpha (Just 5) >>= \y -> return $ x:y:[]
-- returns [[3, 5]]
```

As @duplode pointed out, you can find `alpha` in the package `Data.Maybe` as `maybeToList`.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this `alpha` is available as `maybeToList` from `Data.Maybe`.